# How to display geofield data in openlayers map in the node in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, maps, openlayers

I know how to display the geofield data in a map (openlayers map) in a view, but I don't know how I can display it in the node page itself, anyone can help me out with with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to go to your content type `Manage Display` page and set your geofield formatter to `Geofield Map` or `OpenLayers` then use the right button to change the formatter options.